# How to set one field in every document to null in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

In Solr, how do I set one field in every document to null. From what I can see it looks like I have to update every document like this:

```
{"id":"someId","fieldToMakeNull":{"set":null}}
```

meaning I would have to retrieve every document to get its id. Is there some sort of update by query I can use similar to the delete by query ?

```
{"delete": { "query":"QUERY" }}
```

Would be nice if there is something like this:

```
{"update": { "query":"*:*","fieldToMakeNull":{"set":null}}}
```

I know I can delete the whole index and start from scratch, but this is not very efficient in my case since the index takes many steps to build. Just don't want to have to loop through every document.

Thanks,

Warren

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to loop thru every document - Solr does not have a bulk update facility.

Comment: And your index must support atomic updates (meaning all fields must at least be `stored="true"`).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.